# Convert http get request image into Excel ActiveSheet.Pictures

Tags: excel, vba, serverxmlhttp

I have an image I get from request.responseBody, how can I pass it to excel without using a temp file in my computer storage?

Details:

- I'm using a rest API with the image in the response body
- I don't want to have a temp files in my desktop
- Challenge is to convert the response from the API to Pictures.Insert or Shapes.AddPicture

I'm using something like this:

```
Sub GetPicAPI()
    Dim myUrl As String         ' path of image
    Dim myPicture As Picture    ' embedded image
    Dim MyImage As String       ' create string to receive image in text format
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim datim As String
    
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    datim = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss") 'datetime to generate file
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\phototemp" & datim & ".jpeg"
    myUrl = "https://images.contoso.com/api/GetPic?pwd=1234=&id=1234res=low"
    request.Open "GET", myUrl, False         ' Where to get image
    request.send                             ' Send the request for the webpage.
    MyImage = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)  ' Get the webpage response text into response variable.
    Open myFile For Output As #1  'open file to save image
    Print #1, MyImage             'write to file
    Close #1                      'close file
    Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(myFile) 'put image into cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the URL directly:  `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)`  ?

Comment: For images you can use the `Shapes.AddPicture` method https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture You can use an URL instead of a local path for the parameter `FileName`

Comment: While you can pass the URL directly it will probably still create a temporary file on your computer. Nevertheless using the URL directly has one disadvantage. If an error occurs the only information you get is that the picture could not be inserted. But you will not find out why. I recommend to write some code to download the file and then insert it. This way you have the control about the download and can get detailed information about what went wrong.

Comment: Passing the URL directly "ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)" doesn't work because is the API response as image. The argument needs to be the path to the file or the URL to the image, referencing the filename.jpeg directly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I mean a URL in this form (your profile picture): https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWE79.png Try out what happens if you use your URL https://images.contoso.com/api/GetPic?pwd=1234=&id=1234res=low. If you link the picture directly, then you don't need the xhr retrieval. If it is not directly the image, then only a URL to the image is contained in the responseText and not the image itself. But also consider what Pᴇʜ wrote.

Comment: Actually if you cannot use the URL dircectly (because of what reason ever) then the only way is using a temporary file.

Comment: Ok, I get it after the second coffee of the day. You get the picture as a data stream, not as a file. I assume `Shapes.AddPicture` can't recognise the format then and that's why the insertion fails. In that case I have no other idea than Pᴇʜ mentioned in his last comment.

Comment: Any other ideia to convert the datastream to the addpicture input? The issue is about performance, I have to download multiple images and then write/read from harddrive cost me time.

Comment: Disk read/write time is likely minimal compared to the URL endpoint response and HTTP traffic times...

Comment: @TimWilliams Actually you are right, but I think for thousands of files this still can increase runtime as VBA does not support multi-threading and download does not run parallel to the rest of the code, the download of the next file starts *after* the previous file has been loaded into the worksheet. • Anyway it is correct that the bottleneck here is definitly the internet connection which is very likely much slower than writing to a harddisk.

Comment: @odew It can easily be tested how much overtime the disk creates for your process. How many pictures do you have to download? Let's assume 1000. Check how long it takes to open and wirte random data of several kilo bytes to 1000 files. This is the maximum overhad writting to the HDD can create (SSDs are even faster). 1000 files should be written in a not relevant time compared to downloading them. So this can be ignored (like if downloading them all takes 5 minutes and writing to disk 20 seconds in total, nobody cares).

Comment: I have a similar problem, trying to add an image to an Excel file from a System.Drawing.Image object holding a barcode. I create 1000s of these per day with unique serial numbers for the barcodes. In each case I have to save the barcode from memory to a diskfile, then use Shapes.AddPicture to bring the image back from disk into memory again. Add to that the disk file management of many thousands of jpg files and it does seem like there would be a better way. I came here looking for a better option but this thread is confirming that saving to disk is the generally-accepted answer.

Comment: @MarkF If you want to ask something please start a new question. Note that the 1000 files need not to be managed on your disk, you can use the same file/filename over and over. If you use `LinkToFile:=False` in your `Shapes.AddPicture` the picture gets embedded instead of linked to the filename. This way you can delete the file on the disk right after adding it (a copy is saved within the Excel file now). So everything you need is in the Excel file itself (eg. if you send it to someone else who doesn't have the pictures on disk it still works).